# Metadata update statement is not allowed by the current database SQL dialect 1

Tags: stored-procedures, firebird, firebird-psql

I'm working with a Firebird 2.5 database and need a way to count weekdays within a month. To achieve this, I wanted to create a stored procedure:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE GetWorkingDays (Start_Date DATE, End_Date DATE)
RETURNS (Working_Days INTEGER)
AS
BEGIN
  Working_Days = 0;
  WHILE (Start_Date <= End_Date) DO
  BEGIN
    IF ((EXTRACT(WEEKDAY FROM Start_Date) NOT IN (0, 6))) THEN
    BEGIN
      Working_Days = Working_Days + 1;
    END
    Start_Date = Start_Date + 1;
  END
  SUSPEND;
END
```

Unfortunately, I'm encountering the following error and I'm not sure how to proceed. Can anyone help?

```
Error: GDS Exception. 335544569. Dynamic SQL Error
SQL error code = -817
Metadata update statement is not allowed by the current database SQL dialect 1
SQLState:  42000
ErrorCode: 335544569
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're currently connecting to a dialect 1 database with a dialect 3 connection, or using a driver that prepares statements as dialect 3, even when using a dialect 1 connection.

The dialect 1 `DATE` data type is actually a date+time, and was renamed to `TIMESTAMP` in dialect 3 (to match the SQL standard name). The dialect 3 `DATE` is a date only, which doesn't exist in dialect 1. This is what causes the error.

There are two possible options:

1. Make sure you connect with dialect 1 (e.g. some drivers need an explicit connection property)
2. or replace occurrences of `DATE` with `TIMESTAMP` in your script.

That said, dialect 1 was deprecated 25 years ago in InterBase 6.0, and you should not be using it. You need to upgrade your database to dialect 3. The InterBase 6.0 Getting Started Guide (available from https://firebirdsql.org/en/reference-manuals/ under "InterBase 6.0 Manuals" in the "Full set, cross-referenced") provides instructions how to upgrade.

Comment: I replaced 'DATE' with 'TIMESTAMP', that worked for me. Thank you!

Comment: @Marcin It is a workaround, but it does mean that there is a mismatch between your client working partially or fully in dialect 3, while your database is a dialect 1 database. That is not good. You need to look at fully migrating your database to dialect 3.

Comment: I understand, but this is a database of an CMR that is being maintained by the company which created the app.

Answer (score 0):

As I can understand in your error you are using dialect 1 with your database and it is deprecated for a long time.

You can check your database dialect using this query

```
SELECT MON$SQL_DIALECT FROM MON$DATABASE
```

you can use [gfix utility](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/firebirddocs/gfix/firebird-gfix.html#gfix-dialect) to change your dialect

```
gfix -SQL_dialect 3 dynamo -user SYSDBA -password XXX
```

Comment: Do not just update your SQL dialect to 3 like this. There can be more involved, especially if you have a lot of existing data, stored procedures and triggers. Dialect 3 changes the behaviour of calculations performed with the numeric and decimal types, and changes the storage of numeric and decimal with a precision of 10 or higher.

Answer (score -1):

Would it solve it?

```
Create Procedure GetWorkingDays (
    Start_Date DATE,
    End_Date DATE)
RETURNS (
    Working_Days INTEGER)
AS
DECLARE VARIABLE Current_Date DATE;
BEGIN
    Working_Days = 0;
    Current_Date = :Start_Date;
    WHILE (Current_Date <= End_Date) DO
    BEGIN
        IF (EXTRACT(WEEKDAY FROM Current_Date) NOT IN (0, 6)) THEN
        BEGIN
            Working_Days = Working_Days + 1;
        END
        Current_Date = Current_Date + 1;
    END
    SUSPEND;
END;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).